# CakePHP: bootstrap x-editable data not saved

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, x-editable

I want to inline edit a variable on the list page using bootstrap x-editable. I have used this feature before, but on a table with just one ID and one value which worked well. Now in this case the user clicks on the username in an overview page of contents. On click the username turns into a select box with usernames. This works well. But on save the data is not stored. At least it's stored as 0

In the view:

```
<a href="#" data-name="newValue" class="xedit-username editable editable-click" 
data-url="/contents/editassignee/<?php echo $content['Content']['id'];?>"><?php echo $content['User']['username'];?></a>
```

On click this is turned into (which seems ok):

```
<a href="#" data-pk="5" data-name="newValue" class="xedit-username editable editable-click editable-open" 
data-url="/contents/editassignee/5" style="display: none;">alvin</a>
<span class="editable-container editable-inline">
<div>
    <div class="editableform-loading" style="display: none;"></div>
    <form class="form-inline editableform" style="">
        <div class="form-group"><div>
        <div class="editable-input">
            <select class="form-control input-medium">
                <option value="1">alvin</option>
                <option value="83">robert</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</span>
```

The script for activating the select box is:

```
$('.xedit-username').editable({
    type: 'select',
    title: 'Select username',
    source: '/users/listing',
    showbuttons: false
});
```

And after save, this function in the content controller is used:

```
public function editassignee($id = null) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->Content->id = $id;
    $this->Content->saveField('user_id', $_POST['newValue']);
}
```

Really hope some one sees where I go wrong here, or maybe some one can tell me what's the easiest way to debug. Thanx in advance

Comment: Use your browser developer tools (Right click, Inspect Element, Network tab), test it and see what data is actually being posted

Comment: Got it. It seems like a flaw in the x-editable documentation. data-name="newValue" is not the name of the data sent. But it's like this: name=newValue&value=1&pk=7 => Thanx Ananth

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with x-editable but shouldn't the select have a name value;